# Are additional IRC commands possible by using common IRC clients?

Tags: java, irc

I wanna implement the IRC protocols in Java.
In general, I have a question about additional commands which do not exist in the protocols.

For example, adding a "dice" command with a random number generation.
I could implement the DICE command using PRIVMSG ("* user_x dices 5").
But this would be exactly the same when a user writes "/me dices 5".
So this is not a good way because the user can cheat ;-).

Is there a better way to implement additional commands to IRC?
How can these commands be used by common IRC clients?

Comment: Parse them on the server.

Comment: of course - but how can you reply the clients?
especially to see the difference between a PRIVMSG : ACTION and a DICE - because they should look differently (without adapting all current IRC clients)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some services packages and ircds (e.g. inspircd, unrealircd) used to allow you to push a RAW string to clients:

https://wiki.inspircd.org/InspIRCd_Spanning_Tree_1.2/PUSH

Using this you could push a channel numeric to the user, which can't be spoofed.

Note that these hacks can cause your clients to become desynchronised with the network (their information stored locally differs from what the server has). Use with caution!

Remeber that you'll need to be running the network and services yourself to be able to do this and your bot will need an extremely high level of privileges so you can't just do this on freenode, efnet, etc.

You may be better off doing this as a module in a services package.

Hope this helps!